# php function stream_set_timeout doesn't work as i expect

Tags: php

I everyone,

I'm trying to make this piece of code works, as i set the timeout of the fread function at 10 (fread reads only 2 caracteres) why does it return "Time out !" ?

Here is the code:

```
<?p
 $url = "127.0.0.1:8081/SQLi/cible.php?id=sam";


$fp = fsockopen($url);


if (!$fp) {
          echo "Can't open\n";
     } else {


  stream_set_timeout($fp, 10);  // 10 seconds for fread to be executed

  $res = fread($fp, 2);         // read 2 caracteres of $fp

  $info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);


  fclose($fp);
  if ($info['timed_out']) {
     echo 'Timed out !';
  } else {
     echo $res;
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: You can't just open a socket to a http port and expect to get data. The server is expecting YOU to write a request before it sends anything. See the first example on the [fsockopen documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#refsect1-function.fsockopen-examples)

Comment: Thank you Gerald, is it possible to change this code a bit to retrieve the time needed to load the URL ?

Comment: Of course it is possible. Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just realized that i never answered to this post correctly, so to complete what Gerald said, fsockopen just open a socket on a URL, but it DOESN'T correspond to a GET request, so i had to manually do the GET request to the server so this latter can answer me...

Here is the update code:

```
<?php

$url = "www.google.fr";


$fp = fsockopen($url,80,$errno,$errstr,30);


if (!$fp) {


  echo "Can't open\n";
     } 

else {

  $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  $out .= "Host: www.google.fr\r\n";
  $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

  fwrite($fp, $out);

  stream_set_timeout($fp, 10);  // 10 seconds for fread to be executed

  $res = fread($fp, 200);         // read 2 caracteres of $fp

  $info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);


  fclose($fp);
  if ($info['timed_out']) {
     echo 'Timed out !';
  } else {
     echo $res;
  }

}

?>
```